# what is the equivilent of facebook api me?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a script that will post to my facebook page and I assume all I have to do is modify my code for posting to a users stream.

```
$attachment = array
(
  ...
);
$result = $facebook->api($user.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

What do I put instead of the user's id? I am not sure if it is simply my page's id. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the post owner to be the *user* or the *page*?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I want the user to be the owner of the page

Comment: What?! I was asking if you want to post as admin or [as page](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/). You can't make users admin on pages (and obviously not owners!)

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question, but to post to the current user's page, use `/me/feed`.

Comment: oh, sorry @ifaour I am new to facebook api so I apologize if I'm not very clear. I want to post as the page itself. What I was talking about in my previous post was that I wanted to post to my page as the user(who initiated the posting) if this is not possible, then posting to my page as the page is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *my facebook page* means *my feed* you simply do

```
$user = 'me';
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. POST ON PAGE'S WALL AS *USER*:**
Publishing on a Page's wall *as user* is straight forward, you could use something like:

```
<?php
// path to sdk
require './src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
try {
    $post_id = $facebook->api('/TARGET_PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST', array('message'=>"I am a user!"));
    var_dump($post_id);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_stream'));
}
// rest of code here
```

Note:

- The owner of the post will be the current connected user.
- the above depends on the page's *Posting Ability* settings.
- you need the `publish_stream` permission

**2. POST ON PAGE'S WALL AS *PAGE*:**
Now to post as a Page you could use something like:

```
<?php
// This code is just a snippet of the example.php script
// from the PHP-SDK <http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php>
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'app_secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $page_id = 'TARGET_PAGE_ID';
    $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
    if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
            'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
        );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
}
// rest of code
?>
```

Notes:

- You need the `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions
- Once you obtain the page's `access_token` you can start posting on its behalf
- More about this is explained in depth in my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/).